# Webspher TimeOutException

Tags: java, websphere-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOprc.png)
When sending a lot of data, there is an error (less data is not encountered) but the receiver still saves the data in the database, the party sends the timeout message, how to fix it?